# Why does quicklisp need "root" privilege?

Tags: clisp, quicklisp

The root user can install quicklisp successfully. Howvever the ordinary user cannot.

I do not know why. Could anyone here shed a light on me?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `root` privileges in order to use or install Quicklisp.

The “permission denied” error you're getting is a general Unix issue, not a Quicklisp one.  It results from you having installed Quicklisp as `root`.  Your `~/quicklisp` directory is now owned by `root` while it ought to be owned by your non-`root` user account.  The simplest solution is to remove the `~/quicklisp` directory and start over without using `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

sorry did not catch it well with given short message.

I guess with root privilege, one can **install** the files to `/usr` or somewhere, while commonly ordinary user are not granted to do.

haven't be using quicklisp, but i guess running it does not require special privilege.